# How to support secure http connection from org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet

Tags: java, http

I am using `org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet` class to download an image but I found that it is not supporting https images. Here is the code (actually from an ex-coworker who left):

```
public HttpResponse getHttpResponse(String url, Map<String, String> headers, String username, String password) {
    try {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        if (headers != null && !headers.isEmpty()) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> header : headers.entrySet()) {
                httpGet.addHeader(header.getKey(), header.getValue());
            }
        }
        if (username != null && password != null) {
            addBasicAuthentication(httpGet, username, password);
        }

        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        httpParams.setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, connectionTimeout);
        httpParams.setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, socketTimeout);
        httpParams.setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE, socketBufferSize);

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        return httpResponse;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.error(ex);
        return null;
    } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
        logger.error(ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Commons HTTP? Are you getting an error, or is it just not working? Can you include any stack traces that might be relevant if it's an error?

Comment: It is not working simply (there is no exception). Not so sure about the version but it should be quite recent (the work was done about a month ago).

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  What does it return?